# How to send a RapidJSON::Document as a json, not a string, over HTTP?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

From RapidJSON tutorials and examples, I learned how to get a string from a `Document`. But I want to send the json not the string in HTTP request/response. I failed to find a way to do this. Any examples? Thanks.

Comment: JSON is a string!? To be more precise, it is a textual representation of the underlying data.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hi! Okay... so I can just send the byte representation of the string over HTTP and receive it, construct a string from these bytes then parse the string to a json...?

Comment: You can send the `char []` *contents* of the string over http, and interpret those as json on the other side, yes. The data members of `std::string` are not the text, that is allocated elsewhere. (aside from small strings)

Comment: @Caleth Thanks. `c_str` then... Let me have a try...